# How to sum a value of another column if column A = column B?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have 3 columns with static values. I want to sum value in same row from column D if column A = column E

So the format looks like this:
`val1 | val2 | val3 | sumVal | compareVal`

How do I sum values from sumVal if val1 = compareVal? This has to consider all values row-wise to calculate the total. So if I have 2 rows where val1 = sumVal for the respective row values, it should sum the sumVal of those 2 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A6=E2:E6,D2:D6))
```

If you don't have Office 365, you need to confirm that formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Don't use wholes columns, only the rows with values.

[image]

Comment: Ahh. Ok, so the ctrl+shift+enter is what fixed the issue for me. What exactly does that do? I had this formula but wasn't producing the desired result until I did that

Comment: It is how to enter Array formulas in Excel. Array formulas can process a range instead of just a single cell. The condition in the IF statement compares two ranges, not just two cells, for example. And the TRUE part returns a range, not just a cell. That is called array processing. Excel 365 now has array behaviour by default, and the distinction no longer matters. But in older versions, you still have to use the Ctrl+Shift+Enter.